# TYPO3, Form Framework: Remove jQuery Datepicker from Wizard

Tags: typo3

Is there an easy way to remove the "jQuery Datepicker" Element from the form wizard?

In TYPO3 11 we don't want to use jQuery anymore, so this element is useless.

[image: remove jQuery datepicker]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the ***formElementsDefinition*** of ***DatePicker*** in your own form configuration to ***null***

FormSetup (see [here](https://github.com/TYPO3-CMS/form/blob/main/Configuration/Yaml/FormSetup.yaml)) includes DatePicker (see [here](https://github.com/TYPO3-CMS/form/blob/main/Configuration/Yaml/FormElements/DatePicker.yaml)).

Extend the default configuration by your own:

```
plugin.tx_form {
    settings {
        yamlConfigurations {
            100 = EXT:your_extension/Configuration/Yaml/Form/FormSetup.yaml
        }
    }
}

module.tx_form {
    settings {
        yamlConfigurations {
            100 = EXT:your_extension/Configuration/Yaml/Form/FormSetup.yaml
        }
    }
}
```

In your own configuration, set DatePicker to null:

```
TYPO3:
  CMS:
    Form:
      prototypes:
        standard:
          formElementsDefinition:
            DatePicker: null
```

Comment: The "set DaterPicker to null" Part was all I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The wizard is configured via a YAML file (loaded via the following TypoScript (see EXT:form/ext_localconf.php)):

```
module.tx_form {
    settings {
        yamlConfigurations {
            10 = EXT:form/Configuration/Yaml/FormSetup.yaml
        }
    }
}
```

So, overriding (or extending the cascade) should be the way to go.